# SourceTree and Git Flow repository init

Tags: git, atlassian-sourcetree, git-flow

```
sh.exe C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Atlassian\SourceTree\gitflow_local\gitflow\git-flow init -d

flags:WARN  -d --

C:\Program Files (x86)\Atlassian\SourceTree\tools\getopt.exe: invalid option -- 

flags:FATAL unable to parse provided options with getopt.
```

[image: Error Message]

I contacted github account, and want to "Git Flow" and it shows a message like above.

Answer (score 2):

There was a [similar issue reported at Atlassian](https://answers.atlassian.com/questions/180488/git-flow-for-sourcetree-on-windows-doesnt-work):

> It appears though that the issue was a faulty git flow installation prior to the SourceTree install.
>   I removed all git flow installation data and reinstalled SourceTree (after removing all SourceTree data as well)
>
> After reinstallation of SourceTree, all is woorking fine! :)

You can see more about [git-flow installation within a SourceTree context in this issue](https://answers.atlassian.com/questions/259554/how-do-i-resolve-the-not-a-gitflow-enabled-repo-error-when-attempting-to-start-a-feature):

> SourceTree does not install `git-flow` globally on your system.
>   If you want to access it directly from command line, the path should be

```
%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Atlassian\SourceTree\gitflow_local
```

> The `git-flow` command in MsysGit requires some libs to be in place to work. See https://github.com/nvie/gitflow/wiki/Windows#wiki-msysgit
>
> If you really want to use `git-flow` at the git bash, I strongly recommend you to install a fresh copy using the instructions in the link above.
>   If you plan to use `git-flow` BOTH in the command line and in SourceTree, then use the nvie code in the above link.
>   If you want to use ONLY in the command line, install the fork https://github.com/petervanderdoes/gitflow. It works (far) better, but you should pay attention to NEVER use the GUI anymore to issue `git-flow` commands.