# Error occurs when initializing git flow in mac

Tags: git, homebrew, git-flow

I've been practicing git flow, so I installed `git-flow-avh` by *Homebrew*.

But error occurs when I try to initialize git flow by typing `git flow init` in terminal on my MacBook.

The error message is like in the photo below.

I deleted Sourcetree app and typed `git flow init` because the one of the errors mentioned Sourcetree but it was the same result. So I think it's not about Sourcetree.

What can I do to initialize git flow?

By the way, `git init` is well done.

**Errors in terminal:**

[image: errors in terminal]

Comment: Please check might help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26922524/sourcetree-and-git-flow-repository-init

Answer (score 0):

You have a similar issue with [NixOS/nixpkgs issue 25487](https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs/issues/25487) on Linux.
The general problem is the lack of git and getopt

Double-check the [git flow avh installation page](https://github.com/petervanderdoes/gitflow-avh/wiki/Installing-on-Mac-OS-X#post-installation-setup-1):

```
brew install gnu-getopt
```

Make sure git is already installed and in your `$PATH`.